# When does A and exp(B) commuting imply A commutes with B?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

Let $A,B$ $\in GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and  $[A,B] = AB-BA = 0$. My question is about the existence of a $b \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $B = \exp(b) $ and $[A,b] =0 $.

Note that in general $[A,\exp(b)]=0$ does not imply $[A,b]=0$. As an example consider the matrices
$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&i\\i&2\end{bmatrix}$ $B= I$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix}2 \pi i&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} $. We have $[A, \exp(b)] = 0$ but $[A,b] \neq 0$. However, we can replace $b$ with $\widetilde{b}=0$.

I believe in general this could have something to do with the locus in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ where $\exp$ is a local isomorphism. This is the locus of matrices $X$ which have $\lambda_{i} - \lambda_{j} \neq 2 \pi i k $ for  $k \in \mathbb{Z} - 0 $ for any two eigenvalues $\lambda_{i} , \lambda_{j}$ of $X$ . Note that $\exp$ is still surjective when restricted to this locus. Namely, perhaps if we restrict to preimages of $B$ under the exponential in this locus then perhaps the matrices commute. In particular, in the example above $b$ is not in this locus.

Comment: Have look at the following paper: Remarks on commuting exponentials in Banach algebras https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-11/S0002-9939-00-05465-4/ There you find the result (in general Banach algebras) that $e^a e^b=e^b e^a$ implies $ab=ba$ if the spectra of $a$ and $b$ are $2\pi i$-congruence free. This seems somehow related to your problem.